# Why do ECWs go missing when exporting MXD to PDF with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I'm trying to export some MXD maps to PDF with arcpy (ArcGIS 10.1). Everything works fine and dandy except for ECW images, which don't appear in the PDF. However, when I execute the same code from the ArcGIS python console, the ECW is exported. So if I execute this from an external script:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("path\\to\\test.mxd")
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, "path\\to\\test.pdf")
```

I don't get the ECW layer in the PDF. But if I execute the same lines in the console, it works and the ECW layer is exported properly. Also, if I run

```
execfile('export_mxd_to_pdf.py')
```

from the ArcGIS console, I also get the ECW in the PDF. I don't have this problem with other image formats, like JPG.

What's going on here? What's different between the environments? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 5):

I found [FAQ: What are the disadvantages to printing or exporting ArcMap maps that contain MrSID and/or ECW data?](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/28821). I think that explains what you are seeing:

> All MrSID and ECW images in an ArcMap map must be completely
> uncompressed before being processed by the output pipeline. Since
> these raster formats can be compressed at a 1:10 - 1:50 ratio, this
> can result in several gigabytes or more of temporary files. This can
> exceed the available resources of ArcGIS and the Windows operating
> system and result in clipped or **missing output**, application
> failures, and crashes.